# Query on a piece of code in The GNU C Reference Manual

Tags: c

On this [link](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#hello_002ec)

How can I make this piece of code execute and print `Hello, world!` ?

```
if (!greeting)
     greeting = _("Hello, world!");
puts (greeting);
```

The question is really simple actually. What I'd like to do is to compile and run the code so that it prints `"Hello, world!"`

What options should I give to the program binary so that the above desired output is produced?

Comment: I edited my question to make it more clear. I hope this is acceptable now. Please let me know if further changes are needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`_(str)` is just a functio-like macro from `"system.h"` header (and subsequently from another `"gettext.h"` header) that is included in that example. Here is defintion from [`"system.h"`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#system_002eh):

```
/* Internationalization.  */
#include "gettext.h"
#define _(str) gettext (str)
#define N_(str) gettext_noop (str)
```